# Issues understanding Google App Engine key

Tags: google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking at the GAE example for datastoring here, and among other things this confused me a bit.

```
def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)
```

I understand why we need the key, but why is 'Guestbook' necessary? Is it so you can query for all 'Guestbook' objects in the datastore? But if you need to search a datastore for a type of object why isn't there a query(type(Greeting)? Concidering that that is the ndb.model that you are putting in?

Additionally, if you are feeling generous, why in creating the object you are storing, do you have to set parent?

```
greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))
```

Comment: The greeting belongs to a guestbook. In this way you create an entity group for strong consistency. See the docs for details. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** GAE Datastore is one big distributed database used by all GAE apps concurrently. To distinguish entities GAE uses system-wide keys. A key is composed of:

1. Your application name (implicitly set, not visible via API)
2. Namespace, set via [Namespace API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/) (if not set in code, then an empty namespace is used).
3. Kind of entity. This is just a string and has nothing to do with types at database level. Datastore is schema-less so there are no types. However, language based APIs (Java JDO/JPA/objectify, Python NDB) map this to classes/objects.
4. Parent keys (afaik, serialised inside key). This is used to establish entity groups (defining scope of transactions).
5. A particular entity identifier: name (string) or ID (long). They are unique within namespace and kind (and parent key if defined) - [see this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds%28java.lang.String,%20long%29) for more info on ID uniqueness.

See [Key methods](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key) (java) to see what data is actually stored within the key.

**Second:** It seems that GAE Python API does not allow you to query Datastore without defining classes that map to entity kind (I don't use GAE Python, so I might be wrong). Java does have a [low-level API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Interfacehttp://) that you can use without mapping to classes.

**Third:** You are not required to define a parent to an entity. Defining a parent is a way to define entity groups, which are important when using transactions. See [ancestor paths](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Ancestor_Paths) and
[transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Transactions_and_Entity_Groups).

Comment: That seems like an awfully lot just to create a key. But I still don't understand the purpose of defining kind and parent.

Answer (score 2):

That's what a key is: a path consisting of pairs of kind and ID. The key is what identifies what kind it is.

I don't understand your second question. You don't have to set a parent, but if you want to set one, you can only do it when creating the entity.

Comment: I'm stil not sure I understand the concept of a key here. I can accept it, but I'm used to a dictionary where a key is and object of one type that will point to another object of some type. So I don't understand the need for typing. Is there a visual representation of a datastore I can look at? As for the second question, what is the point of a parent? And why is it good or bad to have the key be the parent?